oracle apex pwa dual screen/window
we have a webapp in pwa mode, so the users can install the app on the pc. All users have dualscreen setup and the question is, is there a solution to make a dynamic action directly from the app, expl. button = opens a new window in standalone mode?
we have a solution now with:
javascript:window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:5:&SESSION.::::','_blank');
but this opens in the normal browser and is not in standalone mode.

I would ask this in the official oracle forum . It is watched by the apex dev team too, they might have an answer for your question

i have: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/oracle-apex-pwa-dual-screen-window-2615
